# Using GetObject to edit other workbooks works 1 time out of x

Tags: vba, excel, macros

First, I am a begginer. Any advice is welcome ! Just trying to code at work to save time later managing 100s of files.

I am building an Excel macro and, just as many other users, I am trying to do the following :

- Have the macro "reside" in a workbook "A".
- Trigger the macro using keyboard shortcut from a workbook "B"
- Have the macro do its magic in workbook "B" (which includes copying a sheet from a workbook "C")

This involves, at some point, prompting the user for workbook "C", defining a variable and putting workbook C in it.

The following code is a part of the macro and works only one time out of x and apparently "crashes" without warning or error code or even letting me know it has crashed.

```
'All the following code is in workbook "A"

Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim ffs As FileDialogFilters
Dim DestWkb As Workbook
Dim SourceWkb As Workbook
Dim SourceWkbPath As String

'Set active workbook as destination workbook (this is workbook "B")
Set DestWkb = ActiveWorkbook

'Prompt user for source workbook (this will be workbook "C")
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fd
    Set ffs = .Filters
    With ffs
        .Clear
        .Add "Excel", "*.xlsx"
    End With
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = False Then Exit Sub
    SourceWkbPath = fd.SelectedItems(1)
End With

'Here is where it starts to go wrong..
'This message box will show up with correct data in it :

MsgBox SourceWkbPath

'This line seems to work, as I can see in VB the workbook specified by the user
Set SourceWkb = GetObject(SourceWkbPath)

'From here... it's like there was an Exit Sub. I will rarely see the following msgbox : 

MsgBox "Success"
```

Anybody already faced such a trouble ? Thank you very much!

Comment: Code works fine for me.  Can you crash it while stepping through the code? or only when running straight through.  Is there any error handling?

Comment: I would use `Workbooks.Open(SourceWkbPath)` instead.

Comment: Good suggestion from Doug. Work with the book directly

Comment: Indeed, code works fine when executed directly in the workbook it resides. But when executed from another workbook (triggered via keyboard shortcut), it will barely work 1 time out of 20... either by stepping or running straight.  I tried Workbooks.Open already, but it didn't seem to get any better. Will try again. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

GetObject is used Set reference to an External Application that is already Open.  In the same way CreateObject is used Set a Create a new External Application.

- Added a check to see if a WorkBook of the same name is open.
- Remove Set DestWkb = ActiveWorkbook
- Use ThisworkBook instead
- Added funny message so you know it worked.

```js
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim ffs As FileDialogFilters
    Dim SourceWkb As Workbook
    Dim SourceWkbPath As String
    Dim SourceWkbShortName As String
    'Prompt user for source workbook (this will be workbook "C")
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fd
        Set ffs = .Filters
        With ffs
            .Clear
            .Add "Excel", "*.xlsx"
        End With
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        SourceWkbPath = fd.SelectedItems(1)
        SourceWkbShortName = Mid(SourceWkbPath, InStrRev(SourceWkbPath, "\") + 1)
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    
    Set SourceWkb = Workbooks(SourceWkbShortName)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set SourceWkb = Workbooks.Open(SourceWkbPath)
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    MsgBox """Hello World!""", vbInformation, SourceWkb.Name & " Says:"
```

MSDN Says: ThisWorkbook always returns the workbook in which the code is running.

The question is: "If WorkBook A runs a Macro in Workbook B what does ThisWorkBook refer to?

**WorkBook A**

```
Sub RunExternalCode()
   WorkBookAName= ThisWorkBook.Name

   WorkBookBName = Application.Run ""

End Sub
```

> WorkBook B

```
Function GetThisWorkBooksName()
    GetThisWorkBooksName = ThisworkBook.Name
End Function
```

Result:

> WorkBookAName = "WorkBookA"
>
> WorkBookBName = "WorkBookB"

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. Am I wrong to say that using "ThisWorkbook" is not going to work properly as code is executed from workbook A in workbook B ? As I want to store workbook b in DestWkb, isn't Thisworkbook going to store the workbook the macro is in instead (in this case, workbook A ?).

Comment: ThisWorkBook will always be the workbook that that initiated the code. It's immutable.  But I'll double check..lol